Update sql table and refresh in html
So, I'm sorta new in this topic and was playing around with HTMX, I have this table representing some data from my db, when pressing the svg at the right side of the row, it enables to edit the fields from the table, when done, I want to make a query to update that record, but my question is how to update the record by the ID of the altered row, where should I store the ID to do the following update from that point?
Note: I already know how to make the endpoint, in the server and the request with HTMX, just need a hand with the id topic
This is the EJS template
I know is insecure to show the actual ID in the HTML (please overlook that)
thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <% for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) { %>
        <tr class="row-<%= i %>">
            <td> <%= data[i].id %> </td>
            <td> <%= data[i].name %> </td>
            <td> <%= data[i].phone %> </td>
            <td class="editButton" style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="/public/img/edit.svg" alt="edit"></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</tbody>

I tried to store an array with the id's in front with js and get the altered row id from the click event in the edit button (I don't think thats a good practice)
I tried to update the record by the name and phone before editing, but want to know if there's a more efficient or proper way to do it

Don't just describe  what you tried; show the code for what you tried. and unless your htmx is erroring as well, you should show the rendered html, because that's what the javascript is interacting with.
